# jQuery/JSON/PHP object to C# method

Tags: c#, php, jquery, json, c#-4.0

Hey guys I am new to JSON and I am working with an example I found written in PHP and jQuery (http://wil-linssen.com/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/).

What I am trying to do is take the serialized "order" object and use it in a C# method exactly  like it is being used with PHP in the above example.

So the jQuery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s) 
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#test-list").sortable({ 
    handle : '.handle', 
    update : function () { 
      var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize'); 
      $("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order); 
    } 
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

instead of passing the "order" object to a handler to be processed in PHP like:

```
<?php 
/* This is where you would inject your sql into the database 
but we're just going to format it and send it back 
*/ 
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) : 
  $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item"; 
endforeach; 
print_r ($sql); 
?>
```

I would like to do the exact same thing but use C# 4.0 to work with the object in a method that is in the same page. Is this possible and can someone show me how to do this?

EDIT:
I am using ASP.NET WebForms & C# 4

Thanks so much!

Comment: It depends on what version ASP.NET you're using? WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a vulnerability there.. `SET position = $position`, since an attacker can pass arbitrary get variable name. Not quite an answer, but C# version should consider doing it not the "exact same thing" :)

Comment: Yeah good point. It was just from the example site I got it from to be used as the idea. Good find.